# Why can't I instantiate a reference to a base class at the same time as a pointer to a derived class?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

The simplest example of my question can be seen in the following code snippet:

```
class Handle : public IHandle_<Handle>{
    public:
        Handle(std::unique_ptr<Derived> aDerived)
            : derived(std::move(aDerived)),
              base(*aDerived) {};

        std::unique_ptr<Derived> derived;
        Base& base;
};
```

Here, you can see that the `Handle` class is essentially a wrapper around `Derived`. More importantly, I wish to expose the base class of `Derived`, `Base`, by way of a reference. The reason for this is that, ultimately, I wish for `Handle` to look something like this:

```
class Handle : public IHandle_<Handle>{
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Derived1> myD1;
        std::unique_ptr<Derived2> myD2;

    public:
        Handle(std::unique_ptr<Derived1> aD1)
            : myD1(std::move(aD1)),
              base1(*aD1),
              base2(*aD1){};
        Handle(std::unique_ptr<Derived2> aD2)
            : myD2(std::move(aD2)),
              base1(*aD2),
              base2(*aD2){};

        Base1& base1;
        Base2& base2;

};
```

The reason I wish for `Handle` to work like this is that I am using it as a 'Component' in an 'entity component system', and I'd like for this particular component to be instantiatable from two different concrete implementations of the same two base classes. I mention this because an 'entity component system' design pattern by definition departs from traditional object-oriented programming practices: in other words, I know there are other ways of accomplishing what I am trying to do, however I wish to make it work in some variation of what I have listed here.

**Question**

Why does the simple `Handle` example shown in my first snippet fail? It compiles fine but seg-faults when trying to access a method in `Base`. If I change the order in which I instantiate the member variables of `Handle`, I get some errors at compile time which I think could provide some hints but I do not really understand what is going on.

Here is a full working example of `Handle` and the classes it depends on:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Base{
    public:
        Base(int ax) : x(ax){};
        virtual ~Base() = 0;
        virtual void setVal(float a) = 0;
        virtual float getVal() = 0 ;

        int x;
};

Base::~Base(){}

class Derived : public Base{
    public:
        Derived(int ax, int az)
            : Base(ax), z(az){};

        int z;
};

class Concrete : public Derived{
    public:
        Concrete(int ax, int aw, int av)
            : Derived(ax, aw),
              v(av){};
        void setVal(float a) override{
            myVal = a;
        }
        float getVal() override{
            return myVal;
        }
        float myVal;
        int v;
};

class IHandle{
    public:
        virtual ~IHandle() = 0;
};

IHandle::~IHandle(){}

template <class T>
class IHandle_ : public IHandle{
    public:
        virtual ~IHandle_() = 0;
};

template <class T>
IHandle_<T>::~IHandle_(){};

class Handle : public IHandle_<Handle>{
    public:
        Handle(std::unique_ptr<Derived> aDerived)
            : derived(std::move(aDerived)),
              base(*aDerived) {};

        std::unique_ptr<Derived> derived;
        Base& base;
};


int main(){
    // These two pointers are owned by an EntityManager
    std::unique_ptr<Derived> ptr(new Concrete(1, 2, 3));

    // we can get a reference to an IHandle from the EntityManager
    std::unique_ptr<IHandle> aHandle(new Handle(std::move(ptr)));

    // We need, specifically, a `Handle` implementation of `IHandle`
    Handle& handle = static_cast<Handle&>(*aHandle);
    // seg fault on the following line
    handle.base.setVal(10.0);
    std::cout << "a = " << handle.base.getVal() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The members in a C++ class are initialized in the order you declare them, so looking at the first snippet, the order of initialization of the members in the Handle class is:

- derived
- base

That said, it means that in the constructor the line

```
derived(std::move(aDerived))
```

will transfer the internal resources of `aDerived` to `derived`, reasonably resetting the state of `aDerived`. So as soon as your code reach the statement

```
base(*aDerived)
```

`base` will reference an *empty* (depends on your move constructor implementation inside Base and Derived class) object that most likely will be deleted from memory after the call of the constructor itself.

So, I believe that any reference to `base` you got in your code are pointing to a not allocated memory, giving the SEG_FAULT error.

SEG_FAULT most of the time refers to code that is using (in your case writing, see setval() ) an area of memory not (yet or anymore) allocated for the running process.

Hope this may help,
Have a good night, 
Stefano

Comment: This answer would be improved if it included a solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: I think I provide a "why". But following your comment, absolutely reasonable: @wesanyer, what's the need for a base class reference? why do you need it in your context?